Confusion on the definition of span
Definition 1:
if span$(v_{1}, v_{2}, .., v_{m})$ equals $V$, we say that the list $v_1, ..., v_m$ spans $V$
Does it mean:
span$(v_1, ... , v_m) = V \implies v_1, ... , v_m$ spans $V$
or
span$(v_1, ... , v_m) = V \iff v_1, ... , v_m$ spans $V$
Definition 2:
A vector space is called finite-dimensional if some list of vectors in it spans the space.
Does it mean:
$\exists v_1, ... ,v_m \in V$ such that span$(v_1, ... , v_m) = V \implies V$ is finite-dimensional
or
$\exists v_1, ... ,v_m \in V$ such that span$(v_1, ... , v_m) = V \iff V$ is finite-dimensional
My professor doesn't reply to us, please clear up this doubt. Also in general when I read a definition, do I by default consider it to be an iff statement?

It’s an iif and yes more generally take them to be iif by default.

In a definition, it is always “iff” but by tradition, most just say “if”
